# Under linux, how to run application via .html

Tags: c++, html

I am working on a image processing project. I am not familiar with html. Here is what I think.

My C++ application is able to read an image and write the image to file after processing. The procedural is that user can click mouse in a fixed region of my web, and the position data could be passed as parameter to my application, and then my C++ application will use the position data to process the image and output image to file, finally my web display the image.

So is that possible to implement this?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable case for CGI to me.

Comment: one roundabout way to do this without a server is to register a custom mime type with your application as handler, pass the arguments with the custom file and poll with javascript for a change in the target image file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not possible only with HTML.
It should be possible with any server-side scripts written in PHP (for example). Anyway, you can make you program to watch folder uploaded and processed images save into another folder. You will need PHP or something like this though.